# C# access simple C dll

Tags: c#, c, dll

I need use a C dll (not C++) in C#
I tried a basic example. But not worked.

I am using microsoft visual studio. I created a new Project. C++ > Win32 Project Then selected dll and empty project.
In options selected Compile As: "Compile as C Code (/TC)"

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void HelloFromDLL()
{
    printf("DLL Works!\n");
}
__declspec(dllexport) double TestFunc(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return (a+b)*c;
}
```

Defination file: Linker > Input > Module Defination File

LIBRARY TestLib
DESCRIPTION "Description"
EXPORTS
 HelloFromDLL @1
 TestFunc @2

When i use extern "C", it gives error C2059

Without it: If i use function in c# code giving error. If not use but with DllImport code line, working.

```
[DllImport("TestLib.dll")]
public static extern void HelloFromDLL();
```

I tried with and without header file. What i should do?

Comment: use __declspec(dllexport) or a def file, not both. And you need extern "C".

Comment: removed def file, but extern "C" gives error. I cant build Dll with it.

Comment: Then post that error here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case your calling convention for dll are wrong

[DllImport("TestLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void HelloFromDLL();

Default calling conventions are stdcall

You can specify WINAPI, PASCAL or __stdcall in your C code for function prototypes 
or use /Gz compiler switch instead to compile your dll  with stdcall calling conventions

P.S. I assume your dll is available for your c# program and BOOL APIENTRY DllMain() is included into code of your dll

Comment: DllMain is optional, no?

Comment: Thanks for it! As i see extern "C" not necessary.But i discovered one more problem. DLL only works with 32 bit (x86). not with x64.

Comment: you would need a x64 version of your DLL. C# can be built to run 32 or 64 bits. C once built will only run on the architecture it was compiled for.